# XSLT - count whitespace using regular expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like follows,

```
<doc>
    <p>  first sentence</p>
    <p>second sentence</p>
    <p>          third sentence</p>
</doc>
```

I need to count the number of spaces (white space) before start the text in `<p>` nodes. 
So in above example 2,0,10 should be return.

I can use count() function to get the count and separate the white space string using tokenize() but my problem is write a regular expression to get the needed white space. How can I write a regular expression to get those white spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a pattern `^ +` then you will match the start of the string plus a non-empty sequence of space characters

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:variable name="space-count" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^ +">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:sequence select="string-length()"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:sequence select="if (position() eq 1) then 0 else ()"/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$space-count"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

> my problem is write a regular expression to get the needed white
>   space.

Regular expression may not be the best choice here. Try this one-liner:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before(., substring(normalize-space(.), 1, 1)))" />
```